# Add a column to number the rows on a ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a ListView to populate data and I would like to add a column that will number the rows.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: See [this](https://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/auto-generate-row-number-in-aspnet.html?m=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the row number from the item index.

```
<td> <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1%> </td>
```

[Click here for an examle](https://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/auto-generate-row-number-in-aspnet.html)